# how to combine multiple isotope combination filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, filtering, jquery-isotope

I am working on Isotope query and there is this request, where I need to include all the combination to filter out the list.

I have 2 select input, 1 search bar, 2 sliders, 1 multiple select input and may be check box in the future.

I tried to place every selection and all the input fields, but I cant able to combine them. I know I need to use combination "join", but cant able to figure out how to combine all of them or few of them depending upon the choice.

```
filterValue = filterValue.join(', ');
```

here is the code I created. 
[code here](https://codepen.io/Knight143/pen/dRJNxB)

I have not even written the range area code yet.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I recently combined multiple filters by using a function, here it's called concatValues.

```
var filterValue = concatValues( filters );

function concatValues( obj ) {
  var value = '';
  for ( var prop in obj ) {
    value += obj[ prop ];
  }
  return value;
}
```

Comment: Oh. I am using this function to combine all the filters, do I have to define in every filter script or combine everything into one?

Comment: I've created an object called filters and each time a filter is selected, I add it to this object.  I will post the full code if you like.

Comment: I have updated the link: https://codepen.io/Knight143/pen/dRJNxB.
Is it possible to take a look and let me know where I should add ConcatValue Fucntion to add all this filters?